# Get redirect from post does not cause update to view

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redirect, post

I have a post route in express that is queried from an Axios request. Its goal is to simply authenticate a user and redirect them to a protected page. The authentication is successful yet the redirection does not render the new view. Why is `res.redirect` not working and how can I get the redirect to render a new react page?

I have a fairly unique development environment that attempts to replicate a production build:

- I am running the build on OSX Mojave 10.14.6
- I am redirecting my domain website.com and www.website.com to localhost in /etc/hosts
- I have a self signed SSL cert installed via the https package
- I am running node v10.1.0 and express

I have tried each type of redirect (e.g. 301, 302, and 307) by calling `res.redirect(30_, '/myhome')` in which _ is the last number in each request.

I conjectured that firefox might have some default behavior blocking a redirect from a self signed cert. I messed with some browser settings but did not get it to work. I have also replicated this issue in Safari for what it is worth.

### Axios query from front-end in react (myhome.js in pages):

```
axios.post('/login', {
    username: values.username,
    password: values.password,
}).catch(
    err => {
        this.setState({
            error: {
                message: err.response.data.message,
            }
        });
    }
);
```

### Bit of offending code with redirect:

```
// Most route that is queried
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    const {email, username, password} = req.body;


    if((email || username) && password){
       // Either username or password can be used to login
        let creds = {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            username: username
        };
        // Database (mongodb) handles authentication 
        User.authenticate(creds, (err, usr) => {
            if (err) {
                err = new Error(error.BAD_LOGIN);
                err.level = 'warn';
                err.status = status.UNAUTHORIZED;
                return next(err); // Is passed on to error handler via next call (no error logged) 
            }else if(!usr){
                let err = Error('Incorrect username or password.');
                err.status = status.UNAUTHORIZED;
                return next(err); // No error printed
            }

            req.session.userId = usr._id;

            console.log('Success'); // Is printed to  the console

            return res.redirect('/myhome'); // The redirect that fails
        });

        return;
    }

    let err = new Error('Email and password fields required.');
    err.status = status.BAD_REQUEST;
    next(err); // No error logged
});
```

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "website-front-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js -vvvvv",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "lint": "eslint ./ --fix",
    "purgelogs": "rm -rf ./logs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^3.17.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.0.0",
    "css-math": "^0.4.0",
    "email-templates": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "http-status": "^1.3.2",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.3.0",
    "lorem-ipsum": "^2.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.2",
    "next": "^8.0.4",
    "next-compose": "0.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "password-validator": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.7.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-youtube": "^7.9.0",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "units-css": "^0.4.0",
    "urlencode": "^1.1.0",
    "uuid-mongodb": "^2.1.1",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "yargs": "^13.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-svg-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

### Post request to remote address to 127.0.0.1:443:

#### Request Headers POST:

```
Host: www.website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.website.com/signin
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 49
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

The post request returns with status code 302.

#### Response Headers (POST):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: /myhome
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 30
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AHem_Jo7jDFZ0xFz4_saY_da7USFz3VCm.9Uvt%2FW6%2BZ5Krvodm9uRoO7QdBt1snQN6vwBO5rZ3s5U; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 17:34:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Redirect get request to protected routes to 127.0.0.1:443:

### Request 200 GET (follows post):

#### Request Header:

```
Host: www.website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Referer: https://www.website.com/signin
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AHem_Jo7jDFZ0xFz4_saY_da7USFz3VCm.9Uvt%2FW6%2BZ5Krvodm9uRoO7QdBt1snQN6vwBO5rZ3s5U
```

#### Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
ETag: "75c-ZfHLepOsT6dLq3dgAF6hwjkWLN4"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1884
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 17:34:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

The browser makes the post request followed by the get redirect. Yet, the page never renders. How can I redirect to another page?